# Adding multiple files to changelist using --field operator in Perforce

Tags: command-line-interface, perforce

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957155/how-to-create-a-perforce-empty-changelist-from-command-line) asking how to create an empty changelist with the p4 command line utility.  It mentions that you can add files to the new changelist using the --field "Files=" option.  This works well for me if I only want to add one file.  However, I can't seem to add multiple files.

For instance, say I have two test files, I can add both of them with one command:

```
p4 add test1.txt test2.txt
```

Expanding on the method described in the question linked above, I would think I could do this to create a new changelist:

```
p4 --field "Description=test submission" --field "Files= //depot/folder/test1.txt //depot/folder/test2.txt" change -o | p4 change -i
```

However, I receive an error claiming that the desired files aren't in the client view ( think this is because it is reading the whole string as one file).  I can only get it to work with one file at a time, i.e.

```
p4 --field "Description=test submission" --field "Files=//depot/folder/test1.txt" change -o | p4 change -i
```

Any ideas how I might go about adding both files to this new changelist?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of trouble to me.  I personally would just create an empty changeset and then do `p4 reopen -C CLN FILE1 FILE2 ...`.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I am trying to put this in a script, so I need to parse the changelist number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be.

That said, you can use the `+=` operator, like this:

```
p4 --field "Description=test submission" --field "Files=//depot/folder/test1.txt" --field "Files+=//depot/folder/test2.txt" change -o | p4 change -i
```

But don't do that.  These are simpler ways to do the same thing:

```
p4 add test1.txt test2.txt
p4 --field Description=test change -o | p4 change -i
```

or:

```
p4 add test1.txt test2.txt
p4 --field Description=test --field Files= change -o | p4 -Ztag -F "reopen -c %change% test1.txt test2.txt" change -i | p4 -x - run
```

(okay, that last one's not so simple if you're trying to do it as a one line script -- it's very simple if you're just running "p4 change" yourself and can just pass the change number to `p4 reopen`)

(edit) one more, this one fits on one long line:

```
p4 --field Description=test --field Files= change -o | p4 -Ztag -F "add -c %change% test1.txt test2.txt" change -i | p4 -x - run
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the += operator.  I was using the method described because I can't know if there are other files in the default changelist.  Also, I didn't know about the -Ztag functionality.  I had seen it, but I didn't understand how to use it.  I think that is the cleanest method, and I believe it's how the p4v does it as well.

Comment: The other option is to create the changelist first and then open the files in it directly with `p4 add -c CHANGE`.  Mucking about with the spec is sometimes a necessary evil (like when you need to set the description) but there's *usually* an easier way.  :)

Comment: More on those flags in these blog posts: https://www.perforce.com/blog/fun-formatting  https://www.perforce.com/blog/20161-command-line-roundup-0

Comment: Is CHANGE a variable that is always set to the last-created changelist, or would that need to be parsed?  Also, great posts there, thanks for the resource!

Comment: You need to provide the actual changelist number -- it doesn't necessarily need to be the last-created changelist, just any pending changelist you own.  I added an arcane one-liner to my answer to include that option (create changelist first, then use the "p4 change -i" output to construct a "p4 add" command).

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for the help!