# Create a new mapping for an existing perforce workspace using command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, perforce, p4v

Is it possible to create a new mapping for an existing perforce workspace using command line? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
p4 --field 'Client=MyClient' --field 'Root=/usr/foo/myclient' --field 'View=//depot/foo/... //MyClient/foo/...' --field 'View+=//depot/bar/... //MyClient/bar/...' client -o
Client: MyClient

Update: 2017/11/28 20:56:52

Access: 2017/12/12 15:26:01

Owner:  bobdylan

Host:   highway66

Description:
        Created by bobdylan.

Root:   /usr/foo/myclient

Options:        noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir

SubmitOptions:  revertunchanged

LineEnd:        local

View:
        //depot/foo/... //MyClient/foo/...
        //depot/bar/... //MyClient/bar/...
```

```

That simply outputs it to STDOUT. What you need is to append
`... | p4 client -i`. That will create a new client with that form.

Inspired by Sam Stafford, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38969939/1540600.

Please note the '+' sign after the second "View".

Comment: so happy to see --field making the world a better place. :D

Comment: it is, indeed! :-)